# I had error to add text into forestplot using ggplot2

Tags: r

I find some R code to do forest plot using ggplot2, combining figure with text. However, when I run the code, there is an error reported and text frame did not come out, although the figure looks good. I will very appreciate any suggestions on how to correct the code. Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)    
library(gridExtra)

dat <- data.frame(group = factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"),     
       levels=c("F","E","D","C","B","A","G")),    
       cen = c(3.1,2.0,1.6,3.2,3.6,7.6,NA),    
       low = c(2,0.9,0.8,1.5,2,4.2,NA), 
       high = c(6,4,2,6,5,14.5,NA))     

theme_set(theme_bw())   
theme_update(   
     axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),    
     panel.grid.major = element_blank(),    
     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),    
     panel.border = element_blank(),    
     panel.background = element_blank(),    
     axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
     axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),    
     plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines")    
)   

lab <- data.frame(  
          V0 = factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","A","B","C","D","E","F","G",                          
                                 "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","A","B","C","D","E","F","G"),  
           levels=c("G","F","E","D","C","B","A")),  
            V05 = rep(c(1,2,3,4),each=7),     
             V1=c("Occuption","Active","","Inactive","","Inactive","","Recreation", 
                       "Inactive","", "Active","","Inactive","",    
                         "Gender","Men","Women","Men","Women","Men","Women",    
                         "OR",3.1,2.0,1.6,3.2,3.6,7.6)) 

data_table <- ggplot(lab, aes(x = V05, y = V0,  
                  label = format(V1, nsmall = 1))) +    
                  geom_text(size = 4, hjust=0, vjust=0.5) + theme_bw() +    
                  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=c(6.5,7.5))) +  
                  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),     
                  legend.position = "none", 
                  panel.border = element_blank(),    
                   axis.text.x = element_text(colour="white"),#element_blank(), 
                   axis.text.y = element_blank(),   
                   axis.ticks = element_line(colour="white"),#element_blank(),  
                   plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines")) +   
                   labs(x="",y="") +    
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1,4.5))    

p
data_table 

##{r forest_plot_1, fig.width=8, fig.height=4, tidy=F}
grid.arrange(data_table, p, ncol=2)
```

### Something wrong here as shown below:

Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_errorbarh).

> data_table
>   Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (28): yintercept
>
> ### {r forest_plot_1, fig.width=8, fig.height=4, tidy=F}
>
> grid.arrange(data_table, p, ncol=2)
>   Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (28): yintercept

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the horizontal line layer. Here is the code that worked for me

```
data_table <- ggplot(lab, aes(x = lab$V05, y = lab$V0, label = format(V1, nsmall = 1))) +    
geom_text(size = 4, hjust=0, vjust=0.5) + theme_bw() +    
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=6.5)) +  
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=3))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much Engmdik for this!!! Yes, it is the issue with the geom_hline. After removing the geom_hline, it works. It means that your way to add the geom_hline is all right.